# I am new on sqlite3 when I want to create a table on my raspberry,I meet a question insouble this is my code

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi3

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE  tempANDhum_data(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    temperature   NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    humidity  NUMERIC NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last comma within the `CREATE TABLE` command.

Comment: Please upvote and mark the accept the answer if it answers your question, thanks!